# what is a word or a phrase to convey -" no more?

Tags: expressions, slang, pragmatics

> What is a word or a phrase to say when we had **too much** of something weird.

- Example- An enthusiastic friend takes me to a play and its puzzling and rather unimpressive to me and I want to yell-

> No More, Please No More!

Answer (score 2):

*enough*!

interjection
(used to express impatience or exasperation):
Enough! I heard you the first time.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enough

Answer (score -1):

[**nonplus**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nonplus):

> - To put at a loss as to what to think, say, or do; **bewilder**.
>
> The verb nonplus, from the Latin phrase nōn plūs, **"not more**," is well established with the meaning "to surprise and   bewilder."

**Usage Note:**  (TFD)
However, the word is frequently used to mean "to make indifferent, bore," as if the plus part of the word meant "to overcome with excitement."

This usage is still controversial and should probably be avoided, since it may well be viewed as a mistake.

Comment: I don't think the OP would actually say this in the situation described. Also, the last sentence of your answer is an invite to downvote!

Comment: but a good to know word...